# Extract groupid and artifactid from class name

Tags: java, maven

Let's say we have a Maven project with:

```
<groupId>com.group</groupId>
<artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
```

With this structure:

```
com
 -> group
     -> artifact
         -> pka
            -> pkb
                -> MyClass
```

If I execute: `MyClass.class.getName()`, returns: `com.group.artifact.pka.pkb.MyClass`

How I can remove the `groupId(com.group)` and `artifactId(artifact)` from class name?

I want to keep just `pka.pkb.MyClass`

Comment: simple answer to this: Not possible cause there are completely different things. Apart from that why do you need the groupId/ArtifactId in your code?

Comment: It's for logs. I don't need `artifactId` and `groupId` and I want to keep it as short/clean as possible.

Comment: Will the group name always be _something_**.**_something_ and the artifact always a single undotted _something_?

Comment: @KevinAnderson I can't guarantee that. The method will be a part of lib which will be executed in other project.

Comment: What about having each app using the lib communicate its groupid/artifactid to the lib?  It's not optimal, as you'd probably need to hard-code that info in the app, but on the other hand it _would_ just be a one-time  call during initialization.

Answer (score 0):

In general, package names can have any form.

They may or may not start with the groupId and artifactId of the given artifact.

So there is no general way to split them up.

Comment: I thought there is a way to get `artifact` and `group` at execution.

Comment: Yes, but if the package name does _not_ start with the groupId or does not contain the artifactId, what do you do?

Comment: Nothing. I want something like `className.replace(groupId, "");` and same for artifact. Short story: I need the value of groupId and artifactId.